# Cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone C++

Tags: c++

Hi I am working on a school project and have written all of this code from scratch (very simple I know). I am a bit confused, as I have solved all errors but two, and was wondering if someone could take a look over my source code and inform me of what I might be doing wrong, and how to solve it. Thanks!

Here are the errors

> IntelliSense: cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone
>
> IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "double" exists

And my source code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Global Constants
const double BMI_FACTOR = 703;
const double MASS_LOWER_LIMIT = 18.5;
const double MASS_UPPER_LIMIT = 25.0;

//Function Prototypes
double getWeight();
double getHeight();
double setMass(double, double);
string setOverUnder(double);
void showBMI(string, double);

//Begin Main
int main() {

    //Variable Declaration
    double weight;
    double height;
    double BMI; //Body Mass Index
    string healthStatus; //Either Optimal, Under, or Over-weight

    //Get the user's weight
    weight = getWeight();

    //Get the user's height
    height = getHeight();

    //Calculate the user's BMI
    BMI = setMass(weight, height);

    //Determine the user's health status based on BMI
    healthStatus = setOverUnder(BMI);

    //Displays the user's BMI and health status
    showBMI(healthStatus, BMI);

    return 0;

//End Main
}

//Function getWeight
double getWeight() {

    //Local Variable Declaration
    double totalWeight;

    //User Input for Weight
    cout << "Enter weight in pounds." << endl;
    cin >> totalWeight;

    //Return the value for totalWeight to caller
    return totalWeight;

//End Function getWeight
}

//Function getHeight
double getHeight() {

    //Local Variable Declaration
    double totalHeight;

    //User Input for Height
    cout << "Enter height in inches." << endl;
    cin >> totalHeight;

    //Return the value for totalHeight to caller
    return totalHeight;

//End Function getHeight
}

//Function setMass
double setMass(double localVarWeight, double localVarHeight) {

    //Local Variable Declaration
    double totalMass;

    //Calculate the user's BMI
    totalMass = (localVarWeight * BMI_FACTOR) / (localVarHeight * localVarHeight);

    //Return the value of totalMass to the caller
    return totalMass;

//End Function setMass
}

//Function setOverUnder
double setOverUnder(double localVarMass) {

    //Local Variable Declaration
    string wellBeing;

    //Determine user's health
    if (localVarMass < MASS_LOWER_LIMIT)
        wellBeing = string("underweight.");
    else if (localVarMass > MASS_UPPER_LIMIT)
        wellBeing = string("overweight.");
    else
        wellBeing = string("optimal weight.");
    
    //Return the value of wellBeing to the caller
    return wellBeing;

//End Function setOverUnder
}

//Function showBMI
void showBMI(string localVarHealth, double localVarMass) {

    //Display user's BMI
    cout << "Your BMI is " << localVarMass << endl;

    //Display user's health status
    cout << "You are " << localVarHealth << endl;

//End Function showBMI
}
```

Comment: Do you expect everyone to guess which line, in the pile of code you dumped here, is generating this error? Perhaps it will be easier for people to help you if you describe the issue with more specificity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared string as return type in function declaration but have used double instead of string in the definition. That's why it's not compiling.

```
//Function setOverUnder
string setOverUnder(double localVarMass) 
{

//Local Variable Declaration
string wellBeing;

//Determine user's health
if (localVarMass < MASS_LOWER_LIMIT)
    wellBeing = string("underweight.");
else if (localVarMass > MASS_UPPER_LIMIT)
    wellBeing = string("overweight.");
else
    wellBeing = string("optimal weight.");

//Return the value of wellBeing to the caller
return wellBeing;

//End Function setOverUnder
}
```

Answer (score 1):

changing setOverUnder definition to return a string should solve the errors.

> IntelliSense: cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone

Because setOverUnder function declaration (returns string) doesn't match its definition (returns double).

> IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "double" exists

Because you are tring to return a string (wellBeing) from a function setOverUnder that returns double.